# this error annoys me every time I open vs code, How to remove this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: here's the error]

Can someone help me to remove this error cause I'm so annoyed by this. I already removed anaconda in my pc but this thing always pops out. Thank you for the one that will answer my question. I really don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you which line in your PowerShell profile is trying to reference a nonexistent file.

Remove the offending line, apparently line 4, from `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`.